# Android: Cannot query ContactsContract.Directory on HTC

Tags: android, contactscontract

I wrote a sample app that returns contacts data from GAL (company directory, defined as Exchange ActiveSync in "Accounts"). The very same app works perfectly well on a bunch of different devices, but not on HTC I tested with (One X+ with Android 4.1.1 and One VX with 4.0.4).
Basically the query to ContactsContract.Directory.CONTENT_URI returns only directories with IDs of Directory.DEFAULT and Directory.LOCAL_INVISIBLE. On other devices this adds, for example, id=5 with type com.android.exchange. The search from native "People" app works on HTCs also.
This is the full code listing of the two classes
**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.galcontactssearch;

import com.example.galcontactssearch.CursorQueryWrapper.CursorResultIterator;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Directory;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "SEARCH_IN_GAL";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private ArrayList<Long> dirIds;
        private String[] projection;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            final Context context = getActivity();
            String app_ver = null;
            try
            {
                app_ver =context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
            }
            catch (NameNotFoundException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot find version name", e);
            }

            Button searchBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            if(app_ver!=null){
                searchBtn.setText(searchBtn.getText() + " v." + app_ver);
            }
            final EditText text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            final TextView resultsView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.resultsView);
            searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final String searchStr = text.getText().toString();

                     new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                final String result;
                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(searchStr)) {
                                    result = "No input";
                                } else {
                                    result = search(searchStr);
                                }
                                resultsView.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        resultsView.setText(result);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }).start();
                }
            });

            CursorQueryWrapper wrapper = new CursorQueryWrapper(TAG);
            dirIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
            wrapper.query(getActivity(), ContactsContract.Directory.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {
                    Directory._ID, Directory.ACCOUNT_NAME, Directory.ACCOUNT_TYPE
            }, null, null, null,
                    new CursorResultIterator() {
                        @Override
                        public void iterate(Cursor cursor) throws Exception {
                            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
                            if (Directory.DEFAULT != id && Directory.LOCAL_INVISIBLE != id) {
                                dirIds.add(id);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Account: id="+id + " name="+cursor.getString(1) +" type="+cursor.getString(2));
                            }
                        }
                    });
            if (dirIds.isEmpty()) {
                String result = "Cannot find additional accounts";
                Log.e(TAG, result);
                searchBtn.setEnabled(false);
                resultsView.setText(result);
            }else{
                HashSet<String> projSet = new HashSet<String>();
                projSet.add(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME);
                projSet.add(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);
                projSet.add(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME);
                projSet.add(Email.ADDRESS);
                projSet.add(Phone.NUMBER);
                projSet.add(Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE);
                projSet.add(Email.TYPE);
                projSet.add(Phone.TYPE);
                projection = projSet.toArray(new String[projSet.size()]);
            }

            return rootView;
        }

        private String search(final String searchString) {
            final StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
            CursorQueryWrapper wrapper = new CursorQueryWrapper(TAG);
            final Context context = getActivity();
            for (Long id : dirIds) {
                final String idStr = String.valueOf(id);
                Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI.buildUpon().appendEncodedPath(searchString)
                        .appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.DIRECTORY_PARAM_KEY, idStr).build();

                final ArrayList<String> lookupKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
                wrapper.query(context, uri, new String[] {
                    Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
                }, null, null, null, new CursorResultIterator() {
                    @Override
                    public void iterate(Cursor cursor) throws Exception {
                        lookupKeys.add(cursor.getString(0));
                    }
                });
                if (lookupKeys.isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                }

                for (String lookupKey : lookupKeys) {
                    uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI.buildUpon().appendEncodedPath(lookupKey)
                            .appendPath(Contacts.Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY)
                            .appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.DIRECTORY_PARAM_KEY, idStr).build();
                    wrapper.query(context, uri, projection, null, null, null, new CursorResultIterator() {
                        @Override
                        public void iterate(Cursor cursor) throws Exception {
                            String mime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE));
                            if (StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE.equals(mime)) {
                                String result = "Given name:"
                                        + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME))
                                        + " Family name:"
                                        + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME))
                                        + " Display name:"
                                        + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                Log.d(TAG, result);
                                bld.append(result).append('\n');
                            } else if (Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE.equals(mime)) {
                                String result = "Email address:"
                                        + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Email.ADDRESS))
                                        + " with type:"
                                        + Email.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), cursor.getInt(cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(Email.TYPE)), null);
                                Log.d(TAG, result);
                                bld.append(result).append('\n');
                            }
                            else if (Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE.equals(mime)) {
                                String result = "Phone num:"
                                        + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER))
                                        + " with type:"
                                        + Phone.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), cursor.getInt(cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE)), null);
                                Log.d(TAG, result);
                                bld.append(result).append('\n');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    String result = "*************************************";
                    Log.d(TAG, result);
                    bld.append(result).append('\n');
                }
            }
            if (bld.length() == 0) {
                String result = "Cannot find matching contacts for the string '" + searchString + "'";
                Log.d(TAG, result);
                return result;
            }
            return bld.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

**CursorQueryWrapper**

```
package com.example.galcontactssearch;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

public class CursorQueryWrapper {

    private final String tag;
    private QueryInterface queryInterface;

    public static class CursorIteratonInterrupt extends Exception {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1124533346986767621L;
    }

    public static abstract class CursorResultIterator {
        public void iterate(Cursor cursor) throws Exception {
        }

        public boolean shouldIterate() {
            return true;
        }

        public void prepareForIterations(Cursor cursor) {
        }
    }

    public interface QueryInterface {
        Cursor query(Context context, Uri uri, String[] projection,
                String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder);
    }

    public static class ContextQuery implements QueryInterface {

        @Override
        public Cursor query(Context context, Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                String sortOrder) {
            return context.getContentResolver()
                    .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        }

    }

    public CursorQueryWrapper(final String tag) {
        this(tag, null);
    }

    public CursorQueryWrapper(final String tag, QueryInterface queryInterface) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.queryInterface = queryInterface == null ? new ContextQuery() : queryInterface;
    }

    public boolean query(Context context, Uri uri, String[] projection,
            String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder, CursorResultIterator iterator) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        Log.d(tag, "Starting query");
        try {
            StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder(
                    "Running query");
            bld.append("\nUri: ").append(uri.toString());
            bld.append("\nProjection: ").append(projection == null ? "null" : TextUtils.join(", ", projection));
            bld.append("\nSelection: ").append(selection);
            bld.append("\nSelectionArgs: ").append(
                    selectionArgs == null ? "null" : TextUtils.join(", ", selectionArgs));
            bld.append("\nSortOrder: ").append(sortOrder);
            Log.d(tag, bld.toString());
            cursor = queryInterface.query(context, uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
            if (cursor == null) {
                Log.e(tag, "Cannot process the query. The cursor is null as a result of some error.");
                return false;
            }
            Log.d(tag, "Cursor's count is " + cursor.getCount());
            iterator.prepareForIterations(cursor);
            if (iterator.shouldIterate()) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    iterator.iterate(cursor);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!(e instanceof CursorIteratonInterrupt)) {
                Log.e(tag,
                        "Cannot process the query.", e);
                return false;
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        Log.d(tag, "The query is ended successfully");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Additionally, there is [this app, "True contacts"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.psencik.com.android.contacts&hl=en), that is essentially just the stock most recent ICS contacts app compiled. It searches the GAL perfectly on Samsung Galaxy S3, for example, but not on HTC. May someone shed some light on the issue, please?